# execute .sql without IDE

Tags: sql, compilation, execute

how to run an .sql without using an IDE?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most databases have a command-line tool that also allows executing scripts. What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL